# Переключение между звуковыми дорожками в андроид

Tags: android, видео

Содержит ли `VideoView` или `MediaPlayer` функции для управления звуковыми дорожками? Я пока не нашла. А если не содержит, то как реализовать такую функциональность?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно управлять аудио-дорожками отдельно от видео (например переключать аудио-дорожки в контейнере `mkv`) или вы просто не знаете как задать плейлист `mediaPlayer`'y ?

Comment: да, переключать аудиодорожки для видео